# Where Can I Find the Source Code for the Preview App; I Want to Develop Additional Tools to Include in Preview

Tags: preview

I use Preview often, so finally I found a different PDF viewer and editor that was more friendly to use, namely Skim. Skim has features that Preview does not and vice-versa. I am just wondering how I can build on top of the existing Preview application. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you could ask Apple?

Comment: good point Scott xD